# UX: Infinite scroll on multiselect. Show number of items or not?

Tags: pagination, infinite-scroll, multi-select

EDIT: I edited the question, it used to say we could have thousands of items, but realistically it's more like 20-100. The question is about if or not to display the total number of items or not, not about if the dropdown is the correct approach in this case. Thank you for your feedback!

I am having a debate with my UX designer, and I would love to hear your input. In our application, we have a dropdown select, where we can select multiple items to filter stuff in a list. The problem is, this select may have 20-100 items, sometimes more. So, we have two options, pagination or infinite scrolling. We have decided infinite scrolling is the way to go.

The part where we disagree is that the designer says we shouldn't show the total number of items in the list at first sight. He says the user should scroll, and then load more items, and continue doing this until he reaches the end of the list in hope of finding the desired item. He says this is best practice. In my opinion this is not good UX as the user has no way of knowing when this list will end. I say we should show the total number of items at all times. A bonus, would be to show which "page" we are in. As in "showing 1-10 of 87". What do you think? Thank you for your reply!

Should we show the total number of items in the list or not?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing infinite scrolling for a dropdown with thousands of items can be challenging in terms of user experience, irrespective of displaying the total count or not. While indicating the total number can provide some context to the user, it doesn't resolve the primary challenge of navigating such a long list.

A more user-friendly approach might be to integrate an autocomplete or searchable input field. This way, users can quickly filter and select the desired options, making the experience more intuitive and efficient.

Comment: Thanks John! We currently already support searching in the multiselect dropdown box. The other possible solution was to implement a paginated list inside the dropdown. The debate is mainly wether to show the total number of items as soon as the dropdown list is shown. Remember, this is not a country multiselect, as in, the user has no idea how many items there will be. In some cases, we have updward of 1,000 items.

Comment: In that case with a searchable multiselect I don't think the count is very relevant because 99% of users will try to search from the start and the rest will probably do it after realizing there's too many options IMO.

Comment: Okay, just remember that user very likely will not remember what to search. So in most cases they will be scrolling down to find the correct filter.